# My RNN with attention model always predict the same class even if my data is not imbalanced

Tags: python, pytorch, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, attention-model

This is my attention layer code :

## implementation of attention layer

```
**class Attention(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, feature_dim, step_dim, bias=True, **kwargs):
        super(Attention, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        
        self.supports_masking = True
        self.bias = bias
        self.feature_dim = feature_dim
        self.step_dim = step_dim
        self.features_dim = 0
        
        weight = torch.zeros(feature_dim, 1)
        nn.init.kaiming_uniform_(weight)
        self.weight = nn.Parameter(weight)
        
        if bias:
            self.b = nn.Parameter(torch.zeros(step_dim))
        
    def forward(self, x, mask=None):
        feature_dim = self.feature_dim 
        step_dim = self.step_dim
        eij = torch.mm(
            x.contiguous().view(-1, feature_dim), 
            self.weight
        ).view(-1, step_dim)
        
        if self.bias:
            eij = eij + self.b
            
        eij = torch.tanh(eij)
        a = torch.exp(eij)
        
        if mask is not None:
            a = a * mask
        a = a / (torch.sum(a, 1, keepdim=True) + 1e-10)
        weighted_input = x * torch.unsqueeze(a, -1)
        return torch.sum(weighted_input, 1)**
```

This is RNN codes :

```
**# Instantiate the model w/ hyperparams
weights_matrix = weights_matrix
output_size = 13  # number of classes to predict 
hidden_dim = 64
drop_prob = 0.5
# The RNN model that will be used to perform classification
class AttentionLSTM(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, weights_matrix, output_size, hidden_dim, drop_prob):
        super(AttentionLSTM, self).__init__()
        
        # embedding layers
        self.embedding, self.num_embeddings, self.embeddings_size = create_emb_layer(weights_matrix, True)
        # embedding dropout
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout2d(drop_prob)
        
        # First lstm and GRU layers
        self.lstm1 = nn.LSTM(self.embeddings_size, hidden_dim, batch_first=True, bidirectional=True)
        self.gru1 = nn.GRU(hidden_dim * 2, hidden_dim, bidirectional=True, batch_first=True)
        
        # attention layer
        self.attention = Attention(hidden_dim*2, seq_length)
        # Second lstm and GRU layers
        self.lstm2 = nn.LSTM(hidden_dim * 2, hidden_dim, batch_first=True, bidirectional=True)
        self.gru2 = nn.GRU(hidden_dim * 2, hidden_dim, bidirectional=True, batch_first=True)
        # linear
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_dim * 2, hidden_dim * 2)
        self.out = nn.Linear(hidden_dim * 2, output_size)
        
        # activation functions
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid() # for hidden layers
        self.softmax = nn.Softmax(dim=1) # for output layer
        
    def forward(self, x):
        batch_size = x.size(0)
        # embedding output
        x = x.long()
        embeds = self.embedding(x)
        embeds = torch.squeeze(torch.unsqueeze(embeds, 0))
        
        # lstm, and gru outputs
        lstm_out1, _ = self.lstm1(embeds)
        gru_out1, _ = self.gru1(lstm_out1)
        gru_out1 = gru_out1.view(batch_size, -1, hidden_dim * 2)
        attention_out = self.attention(gru_out1, seq_length)
        attention_out = attention_out.view(batch_size, -1, hidden_dim * 2)
        attention_out = self.sigmoid(attention_out)
        lstm_out2, _ = self.lstm2(attention_out)
        # slice lstm_out to just get output of last element of the input sequence
        lstm_out2 = lstm_out2[:, -1]
        gru_out2, _ = self.gru2(lstm_out2)
        # linear outputs
        fc_out = self.softmax(self.fc(gru_out2))
        final_out = self.out(fc_out)
        return final_out**
```

I am sure that my dataset is balanced after pre-processing step but my model always predict the same output. Precision and fscore are changing for each input, however, this problem makes my recall score 1.0 since output is always same whatever input is.
If anybody help me, i will be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It required some time to build networks from your requirements but I provided a few samples to create a customer layer or model, you start from an embedded layer and suddenly random leaves of data create different input every time GRU and LSTM learning layers may provide good results when they had :

1. Matching input and target layer and parameters.
2. Learning scopes when they can differentiate input, repeating of gated current, and LSTM is specifically used when patterns of data are
   significant such as pictures or continue data.
3. Linear, and Sigmoid provide contrast differentiate and softmax sometime we required when compared based on distribution values. This
   is supposed to create contrast output excepted softmax applied on
   weights of values.
4. Loss Fn is based on a similar output dimension/expectation

**[ Sample ]:**

```
class create_emb_layer( tf.keras.layers.Embedding ):
    def __init__( self, weights_matrix, bidirectional=True ):
        self.num_embeddings = weights_matrix[0]
        self.embeddings_size = weights_matrix[1]
        self.bidirectional = bidirectional
        super(create_emb_layer, self).__init__( self.embeddings_size, self.num_embeddings )

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.kernel = self.add_weight("kernel",
        shape=[int(input_shape[-1]),
        self.input_dim])

    def call(self, inputs):
        return tf.matmul(inputs, self.kernel)
```

**[ My model ]:**

```
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Initialize
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=( 32, 32, 4 )),
    tf.keras.layers.Normalization(mean=3., variance=2.),
    tf.keras.layers.Normalization(mean=4., variance=6.),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape((128, 225)),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(96, return_sequences=True, return_state=False)),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(96)),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(192, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(10),
])
```

**[ Output ]:**

[image: Sample]

Comment: Thank you for your interest and reply ! I am really new to coding and dl models. now I am working with pytorch. you explained very well a potential solution but it is keras so i do not know exactly how i transform this code to pytoch. can you help me ? do you think that there should be a layer between embedding and lstm layer? my aim is to build a model to predict one of the news title and there are 13 classes. this is my code for embedding layer :

Comment: ```def create_emb_layer(weights_matrix, non_trainable=False):
    num_embeddings, embedding_dim = weights_matrix.shape
    emb_layer = nn.Embedding(num_embeddings, embedding_dim)
    emb_layer.load_state_dict({'weight': torch.from_numpy(weights_matrix)})
    if non_trainable:
        emb_layer.weight.requires_grad = False

    return emb_layer, num_embeddings, embedding_dim ```

Comment: The topic is PyTorch but you are currently working on Tensorflow, I example the embedded create class and requirements for balance - imbalance.  The output is the result of definition call in the custom embedded class.